# How do I get public IP address similar to what google returns in NGINX?

Tags: nginx

My NGINX configuration is as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /test {
        return 200 $remote_addr;
    }
}
```

When I google my public IP, google returns something like `167.124.xxx.xxx`. But nginx's `$remote_addr` returns something like `192.168.xx.xx`. Why is the IP returned by Google different than what NGINX returns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`192.168.xx.xx` is your server's IP within your network, and `167.124.xx.xx` is your network's public address. This has nothing to do with NGINX specifically. More info [here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=public%20and%20private%20ip).